# How to fix: undefined symbol: PyFPE_jbuf

Tags: python, kivy

This error appears when I run a python KIVY application.
I would like to fix it but I didn't find the reason. According to my researches, it could be due to multisampling, or SDL version, or gnome DE, ...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "appoff.py", line 2, in <module>
     from kivy.app import App
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/app.py", line 319, in <module>
     from kivy.base import runTouchApp, stopTouchApp
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/base.py", line 30, in <module>
     from kivy.event import EventDispatcher
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/event.py", line 8, in <module>
     import kivy._event
 ImportError: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/_event.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: PyFPE_jbuf
```

Python: 3.6.3 (but error appears also with python 2.7) / 
Kivy: 1.10.0 / 
OS: Ubuntu 17.10 / 
DE: GNOME Shell 3.26.1

Output of `python3 -c "import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_config_vars())"` :

```
{'prefix': '/usr', 'exec_prefix': '/usr', 'py_version': '3.6.3', 'py_version_short': '3.6', 'py_version_nodot': '36', 'installed_base': '/usr', 'base': '/usr', 'installed_platbase': '/usr', 'platbase': '/usr', 'projectbase': '/usr/bin', 'abiflags': 'm', 'ABIFLAGS': 'm', 'AC_APPLE_UNIVERSAL_BUILD': 0, 'AIX_GENUINE_CPLUSPLUS': 0, 'ANDROID_API_LEVEL': 0, 'AR': 'x86_64-linux-gnu-ar', 'ARFLAGS': 'rc', 'BASECFLAGS': '-Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare', 'BASECPPFLAGS': '-IObjects -IInclude -IPython', 'BASEMODLIBS': '', 'BINDIR': '/usr/bin', 'BINLIBDEST': '/usr/lib/python3.6', 'BLDLIBRARY': '-lpython3.6m', 'BLDSHARED': 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-link.specs -Wl,-z,relro', 'BUILDEXE': '', 'BUILDPYTHON': 'python', 'BUILD_GNU_TYPE': 'x86_64-pc-linux-gnu', 'BYTESTR_DEPS': '\\', 'CC': 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread', 'CCSHARED': '-fPIC', 'CFLAGS': '-Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.6-sXpGnM/python3.6-3.6.3=. -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-compile.specs -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security', 'CFLAGSFORSHARED': '-fPIC', 'CFLAGS_ALIASING': '', 'CFLAGS_NODIST': '', 'CONFIGFILES': 'configure configure.ac acconfig.h pyconfig.h.in Makefile.pre.in', 'CONFIGURE_CFLAGS': '-g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.6-sXpGnM/python3.6-3.6.3=. -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-compile.specs -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security', 'CONFIGURE_CFLAGS_NODIST': '-std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers', 'CONFIGURE_CPPFLAGS': '-Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2', 'CONFIGURE_LDFLAGS': '-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-link.specs -Wl,-z,relro', 'CONFIG_ARGS': "'--enable-shared' '--prefix=/usr' '--enable-ipv6' '--enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions' '--with-dbmliborder=bdb:gdbm' '--with-computed-gotos' '--without-ensurepip' '--with-system-expat' '--with-system-libmpdec' '--with-system-ffi' 'CC=x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' 'CFLAGS=-g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.6-sXpGnM/python3.6-3.6.3=. -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-compile.specs -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security ' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-link.specs -Wl,-z,relro' 'CPPFLAGS=-Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2'", 'CONFINCLUDEDIR': '/usr/include', 'CONFINCLUDEPY': '/usr/include/python3.6m', 'COREPYTHONPATH': ':', 'COVERAGE_INFO': '/build/python3.6-sXpGnM/python3.6-3.6.3/build-shared/coverage.info', 'COVERAGE_REPORT': '/build/python3.6-sXpGnM/python3.6-3.6.3/build-shared/lcov-report', 'COVERAGE_REPORT_OPTIONS': '--no-branch-coverage --title "CPython lcov report"', 'CPPFLAGS': '-IObjects -IInclude -IPython -I. -I../Include -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2', 'CXX': 'x86_64-linux-gnu-g++ -pthread', 'DESTDIRS': '/usr /usr/lib /usr/lib/python3.6 /usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', 'DESTLIB': '/usr/lib/python3.6', 'DESTPATH': '', 'DESTSHARED': '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', 'DFLAGS': '', 'DIRMODE': 755, 'DIST': 'README ChangeLog configure configure.ac acconfig.h pyconfig.h.in Makefile.pre.in Include Lib Misc Ext-dummy', 'DISTDIRS': 'Include Lib Misc Ext-dummy', 'DISTFILES': 'README ChangeLog configure configure.ac acconfig.h pyconfig.h.in Makefile.pre.in', 'DLINCLDIR': '.', 'DLLLIBRARY': '', 'DOUBLE_IS_ARM_MIXED_ENDIAN_IEEE754': 0, 'DOUBLE_IS_BIG_ENDIAN_IEEE754': 0, 'DOUBLE_IS_LITTLE_ENDIAN_IEEE754': 1, 'DTRACE': '', 'DTRACE_DEPS': '\\', 'DTRACE_HEADERS': '', 'DTRACE_OBJS': '', 'DYNLOADFILE': 'dynload_shlib.o', 'ENABLE_IPV6': 1, 'ENSUREPIP': 'no', 'EXE': '', 'EXEMODE': 755, 'EXTRAMACHDEPPATH': '', 'EXTRATESTOPTS': '', 'EXT_SUFFIX': '.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so', 'FILEMODE': 644, 'FLOCK_NEEDS_LIBBSD': 0, 'GETPGRP_HAVE_ARG': 0, 'GETTIMEOFDAY_NO_TZ': 0, 'GITBRANCH': '', 'GITTAG': '', 'GITVERSION': '', 'GNULD': 'yes', 'HAVE_ACCEPT4': 1, 'HAVE_ACOSH': 1, 'HAVE_ADDRINFO': 1, 'HAVE_ALARM': 1, 'HAVE_ALIGNED_REQUIRED': 0, 'HAVE_ALLOCA_H': 1, 'HAVE_ALTZONE': 0, 'HAVE_ASINH': 1, 'HAVE_ASM_TYPES_H': 1, 'HAVE_ATANH': 1, 'HAVE_BIND_TEXTDOMAIN_CODESET': 1, 'HAVE_BLUETOOTH_BLUETOOTH_H': 1, 'HAVE_BLUETOOTH_H': 0, 'HAVE_BROKEN_MBSTOWCS': 0, 'HAVE_BROKEN_NICE': 0, 'HAVE_BROKEN_PIPE_BUF': 0, 'HAVE_BROKEN_POLL': 0, 'HAVE_BROKEN_POSIX_SEMAPHORES': 0, 'HAVE_BROKEN_PTHREAD_SIGMASK': 0, 'HAVE_BROKEN_SEM_GETVALUE': 0, 'HAVE_BROKEN_UNSETENV': 0, 'HAVE_BUILTIN_ATOMIC': 1, 'HAVE_CHFLAGS': 0, 'HAVE_CHOWN': 1, 'HAVE_CHROOT': 1, 'HAVE_CLOCK': 1, 'HAVE_CLOCK_GETRES': 1, 'HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME': 1, 'HAVE_CLOCK_SETTIME': 1, 'HAVE_COMPUTED_GOTOS': 1, 'HAVE_CONFSTR': 1, 'HAVE_CONIO_H': 0, 'HAVE_COPYSIGN': 1, 'HAVE_CTERMID': 1, 'HAVE_CTERMID_R': 0, 'HAVE_CURSES_H': 1, 'HAVE_CURSES_IS_TERM_RESIZED': 1, 'HAVE_CURSES_RESIZETERM': 1, 'HAVE_CURSES_RESIZE_TERM': 1, 'HAVE_DECL_ISFINITE': 1, 'HAVE_DECL_ISINF': 1, 'HAVE_DECL_ISNAN': 1, 'HAVE_DECL_RTLD_DEEPBIND': 1, 'HAVE_DECL_RTLD_GLOBAL': 1, 'HAVE_DECL_RTLD_LAZY': 1, 'HAVE_DECL_RTLD_LOCAL': 1, 'HAVE_DECL_RTLD_NODELETE': 1, 'HAVE_DECL_RTLD_NOLOAD': 1, 'HAVE_DECL_RTLD_NOW': 1, 'HAVE_DECL_TZNAME': 0, 'HAVE_DEVICE_MACROS': 1, 'HAVE_DEV_PTC': 0, 'HAVE_DEV_PTMX': 1, 'HAVE_DIRECT_H': 0, 'HAVE_DIRENT_D_TYPE': 1, 'HAVE_DIRENT_H': 1, 'HAVE_DIRFD': 1, 'HAVE_DLFCN_H': 1, 'HAVE_DLOPEN': 1, 'HAVE_DUP2': 1, 'HAVE_DUP3': 1, 'HAVE_DYNAMIC_LOADING': 1, 'HAVE_ENDIAN_H': 1, 'HAVE_EPOLL': 1, 'HAVE_EPOLL_CREATE1': 1, 'HAVE_ERF': 1, 'HAVE_ERFC': 1, 'HAVE_ERRNO_H': 1, 'HAVE_EXECV': 1, 'HAVE_EXPM1': 1, 'HAVE_FACCESSAT': 1, 'HAVE_FCHDIR': 1, 'HAVE_FCHMOD': 1, 'HAVE_FCHMODAT': 1, 'HAVE_FCHOWN': 1, 'HAVE_FCHOWNAT': 1, 'HAVE_FCNTL_H': 1, 'HAVE_FDATASYNC': 1, 'HAVE_FDOPENDIR': 1, 'HAVE_FEXECVE': 1, 'HAVE_FINITE': 1, 'HAVE_FLOCK': 1, 'HAVE_FORK': 1, 'HAVE_FORKPTY': 1, 'HAVE_FPATHCONF': 1, 'HAVE_FSEEK64': 0, 'HAVE_FSEEKO': 1, 'HAVE_FSTATAT': 1, 'HAVE_FSTATVFS': 1, 'HAVE_FSYNC': 1, 'HAVE_FTELL64': 0, 'HAVE_FTELLO': 1, 'HAVE_FTIME': 1, 'HAVE_FTRUNCATE': 1, 'HAVE_FUTIMENS': 1, 'HAVE_FUTIMES': 1, 'HAVE_FUTIMESAT': 1, 'HAVE_GAI_STRERROR': 1, 'HAVE_GAMMA': 1, 'HAVE_GCC_ASM_FOR_MC68881': 0, 'HAVE_GCC_ASM_FOR_X64': 1, 'HAVE_GCC_ASM_FOR_X87': 1, 'HAVE_GCC_UINT128_T': 1, 'HAVE_GETADDRINFO': 1, 'HAVE_GETC_UNLOCKED': 1, 'HAVE_GETENTROPY': 1, 'HAVE_GETGROUPLIST': 1, 'HAVE_GETGROUPS': 1, 'HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME': 0, 'HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R': 1, 'HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R_3_ARG': 0, 'HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R_5_ARG': 0, 'HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R_6_ARG': 1, 'HAVE_GETITIMER': 1, 'HAVE_GETLOADAVG': 1, 'HAVE_GETLOGIN': 1, 'HAVE_GETNAMEINFO': 1, 'HAVE_GETPAGESIZE': 1, 'HAVE_GETPEERNAME': 1, 'HAVE_GETPGID': 1, 'HAVE_GETPGRP': 1, 'HAVE_GETPID': 1, 'HAVE_GETPRIORITY': 1, 'HAVE_GETPWENT': 1, 'HAVE_GETRANDOM': 1, 'HAVE_GETRANDOM_SYSCALL': 1, 'HAVE_GETRESGID': 1, 'HAVE_GETRESUID': 1, 'HAVE_GETSID': 1, 'HAVE_GETSPENT': 1, 'HAVE_GETSPNAM': 1, 'HAVE_GETTIMEOFDAY': 1, 'HAVE_GETWD': 1, 'HAVE_GLIBC_MEMMOVE_BUG': 0, 'HAVE_GRP_H': 1, 'HAVE_HSTRERROR': 1, 'HAVE_HTOLE64': 1, 'HAVE_HYPOT': 1, 'HAVE_IEEEFP_H': 0, 'HAVE_IF_NAMEINDEX': 1, 'HAVE_INET_ATON': 1, 'HAVE_INET_PTON': 1, 'HAVE_INITGROUPS': 1, 'HAVE_INTTYPES_H': 1, 'HAVE_IO_H': 0, 'HAVE_IPA_PURE_CONST_BUG': 0, 'HAVE_KILL': 1, 'HAVE_KILLPG': 1, 'HAVE_KQUEUE': 0, 'HAVE_LANGINFO_H': 1, 'HAVE_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT': 0, 'HAVE_LCHFLAGS': 0, 'HAVE_LCHMOD': 0, 'HAVE_LCHOWN': 1, 'HAVE_LGAMMA': 1, 'HAVE_LIBDL': 1, 'HAVE_LIBDLD': 0, 'HAVE_LIBIEEE': 0, 'HAVE_LIBINTL_H': 1, 'HAVE_LIBREADLINE': 1, 'HAVE_LIBRESOLV': 0, 'HAVE_LIBSENDFILE': 0, 'HAVE_LIBUTIL_H': 0, 'HAVE_LINK': 1, 'HAVE_LINKAT': 1, 'HAVE_LINUX_CAN_BCM_H': 1, 'HAVE_LINUX_CAN_H': 1, 'HAVE_LINUX_CAN_RAW_FD_FRAMES': 1, 'HAVE_LINUX_CAN_RAW_H': 1, 'HAVE_LINUX_NETLINK_H': 1, 'HAVE_LINUX_RANDOM_H': 1, 'HAVE_LINUX_TIPC_H': 1, 'HAVE_LOCKF': 1, 'HAVE_LOG1P': 1, 'HAVE_LOG2': 1, 'HAVE_LONG_DOUBLE': 1, 'HAVE_LSTAT': 1, 'HAVE_LUTIMES': 1, 'HAVE_MAKEDEV': 1, 'HAVE_MBRTOWC': 1, 'HAVE_MEMMOVE': 1, 'HAVE_MEMORY_H': 1, 'HAVE_MEMRCHR': 1, 'HAVE_MKDIRAT': 1, 'HAVE_MKFIFO': 1, 'HAVE_MKFIFOAT': 1, 'HAVE_MKNOD': 1, 'HAVE_MKNODAT': 1, 'HAVE_MKTIME': 1, 'HAVE_MMAP': 1, 'HAVE_MREMAP': 1, 'HAVE_NCURSES_H': 1, 'HAVE_NDIR_H': 0, 'HAVE_NETPACKET_PACKET_H': 1, 'HAVE_NET_IF_H': 1, 'HAVE_NICE': 1, 'HAVE_OPENAT': 1, 'HAVE_OPENPTY': 1, 'HAVE_PATHCONF': 1, 'HAVE_PAUSE': 1, 'HAVE_PIPE2': 1, 'HAVE_PLOCK': 0, 'HAVE_POLL': 1, 'HAVE_POLL_H': 1, 'HAVE_POSIX_FADVISE': 1, 'HAVE_POSIX_FALLOCATE': 1, 'HAVE_PREAD': 1, 'HAVE_PRLIMIT': 1, 'HAVE_PROCESS_H': 0, 'HAVE_PROTOTYPES': 1, 'HAVE_PTHREAD_ATFORK': 1, 'HAVE_PTHREAD_DESTRUCTOR': 0, 'HAVE_PTHREAD_H': 1, 'HAVE_PTHREAD_INIT': 0, 'HAVE_PTHREAD_KILL': 1, 'HAVE_PTHREAD_SIGMASK': 1, 'HAVE_PTY_H': 1, 'HAVE_PUTENV': 1, 'HAVE_PWRITE': 1, 'HAVE_READLINK': 1, 'HAVE_READLINKAT': 1, 'HAVE_READV': 1, 'HAVE_REALPATH': 1, 'HAVE_RENAMEAT': 1, 'HAVE_RL_APPEND_HISTORY': 1, 'HAVE_RL_CALLBACK': 1, 'HAVE_RL_CATCH_SIGNAL': 1, 'HAVE_RL_COMPLETION_APPEND_CHARACTER': 1, 'HAVE_RL_COMPLETION_DISPLAY_MATCHES_HOOK': 1, 'HAVE_RL_COMPLETION_MATCHES': 1, 'HAVE_RL_COMPLETION_SUPPRESS_APPEND': 1, 'HAVE_RL_PRE_INPUT_HOOK': 1, 'HAVE_RL_RESIZE_TERMINAL': 1, 'HAVE_ROUND': 1, 'HAVE_SCHED_GET_PRIORITY_MAX': 1, 'HAVE_SCHED_H': 1, 'HAVE_SCHED_RR_GET_INTERVAL': 1, 'HAVE_SCHED_SETAFFINITY': 1, 'HAVE_SCHED_SETPARAM': 1, 'HAVE_SCHED_SETSCHEDULER': 1, 'HAVE_SELECT': 1, 'HAVE_SEM_GETVALUE': 1, 'HAVE_SEM_OPEN': 1, 'HAVE_SEM_TIMEDWAIT': 1, 'HAVE_SEM_UNLINK': 1, 'HAVE_SENDFILE': 1, 'HAVE_SETEGID': 1, 'HAVE_SETEUID': 1, 'HAVE_SETGID': 1, 'HAVE_SETGROUPS': 1, 'HAVE_SETHOSTNAME': 1, 'HAVE_SETITIMER': 1, 'HAVE_SETLOCALE': 1, 'HAVE_SETPGID': 1, 'HAVE_SETPGRP': 1, 'HAVE_SETPRIORITY': 1, 'HAVE_SETREGID': 1, 'HAVE_SETRESGID': 1, 'HAVE_SETRESUID': 1, 'HAVE_SETREUID': 1, 'HAVE_SETSID': 1, 'HAVE_SETUID': 1, 'HAVE_SETVBUF': 1, 'HAVE_SHADOW_H': 1, 'HAVE_SIGACTION': 1, 'HAVE_SIGALTSTACK': 1, 'HAVE_SIGINTERRUPT': 1, 'HAVE_SIGNAL_H': 1, 'HAVE_SIGPENDING': 1, 'HAVE_SIGRELSE': 1, 'HAVE_SIGTIMEDWAIT': 1, 'HAVE_SIGWAIT': 1, 'HAVE_SIGWAITINFO': 1, 'HAVE_SNPRINTF': 1, 'HAVE_SOCKADDR_ALG': 1, 'HAVE_SOCKADDR_SA_LEN': 0, 'HAVE_SOCKADDR_STORAGE': 1, 'HAVE_SOCKETPAIR': 1, 'HAVE_SPAWN_H': 1, 'HAVE_SSIZE_T': 1, 'HAVE_STATVFS': 1, 'HAVE_STAT_TV_NSEC': 1, 'HAVE_STAT_TV_NSEC2': 0, 'HAVE_STDARG_PROTOTYPES': 1, 'HAVE_STDINT_H': 1, 'HAVE_STDLIB_H': 1, 'HAVE_STD_ATOMIC': 1, 'HAVE_STRDUP': 1, 'HAVE_STRFTIME': 1, 'HAVE_STRINGS_H': 1, 'HAVE_STRING_H': 1, 'HAVE_STRLCPY': 0, 'HAVE_STROPTS_H': 1, 'HAVE_STRUCT_PASSWD_PW_GECOS': 1, 'HAVE_STRUCT_PASSWD_PW_PASSWD': 1, 'HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_BIRTHTIME': 0, 'HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_BLKSIZE': 1, 'HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_BLOCKS': 1, 'HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_FLAGS': 0, 'HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_GEN': 0, 'HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_RDEV': 1, 'HAVE_STRUCT_TM_TM_ZONE': 1, 'HAVE_SYMLINK': 1, 'HAVE_SYMLINKAT': 1, 'HAVE_SYNC': 1, 'HAVE_SYSCONF': 1, 'HAVE_SYSEXITS_H': 1, 'HAVE_SYS_AUDIOIO_H': 0, 'HAVE_SYS_BSDTTY_H': 0, 'HAVE_SYS_DEVPOLL_H': 0, 'HAVE_SYS_DIR_H': 0, 'HAVE_SYS_ENDIAN_H': 0, 'HAVE_SYS_EPOLL_H': 1, 'HAVE_SYS_EVENT_H': 0, 'HAVE_SYS_FILE_H': 1, 'HAVE_SYS_IOCTL_H': 1, 'HAVE_SYS_KERN_CONTROL_H': 0, 'HAVE_SYS_LOADAVG_H': 0, 'HAVE_SYS_LOCK_H': 0, 'HAVE_SYS_MKDEV_H': 0, 'HAVE_SYS_MODEM_H': 0, 'HAVE_SYS_NDIR_H': 0, 'HAVE_SYS_PARAM_H': 1, 'HAVE_SYS_POLL_H': 1, 'HAVE_SYS_RANDOM_H': 1, 'HAVE_SYS_RESOURCE_H': 1, 'HAVE_SYS_SELECT_H': 1, 'HAVE_SYS_SENDFILE_H': 1, 'HAVE_SYS_SOCKET_H': 1, 'HAVE_SYS_STATVFS_H': 1, 'HAVE_SYS_STAT_H': 1, 'HAVE_SYS_SYSCALL_H': 1, 'HAVE_SYS_SYSMACROS_H': 1, 'HAVE_SYS_SYS_DOMAIN_H': 0, 'HAVE_SYS_TERMIO_H': 0, 'HAVE_SYS_TIMES_H': 1, 'HAVE_SYS_TIME_H': 1, 'HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H': 1, 'HAVE_SYS_UIO_H': 1, 'HAVE_SYS_UN_H': 1, 'HAVE_SYS_UTSNAME_H': 1, 'HAVE_SYS_WAIT_H': 1, 'HAVE_SYS_XATTR_H': 1, 'HAVE_TCGETPGRP': 1, 'HAVE_TCSETPGRP': 1, 'HAVE_TEMPNAM': 1, 'HAVE_TERMIOS_H': 1, 'HAVE_TERM_H': 1, 'HAVE_TGAMMA': 1, 'HAVE_TIMEGM': 1, 'HAVE_TIMES': 1, 'HAVE_TMPFILE': 1, 'HAVE_TMPNAM': 1, 'HAVE_TMPNAM_R': 1, 'HAVE_TM_ZONE': 1, 'HAVE_TRUNCATE': 1, 'HAVE_TZNAME': 0, 'HAVE_UCS4_TCL': 0, 'HAVE_UNAME': 1, 'HAVE_UNISTD_H': 1, 'HAVE_UNLINKAT': 1, 'HAVE_UNSETENV': 1, 'HAVE_USABLE_WCHAR_T': 0, 'HAVE_UTIL_H': 0, 'HAVE_UTIMENSAT': 1, 'HAVE_UTIMES': 1, 'HAVE_UTIME_H': 1, 'HAVE_WAIT3': 1, 'HAVE_WAIT4': 1, 'HAVE_WAITID': 1, 'HAVE_WAITPID': 1, 'HAVE_WCHAR_H': 1, 'HAVE_WCSCOLL': 1, 'HAVE_WCSFTIME': 1, 'HAVE_WCSXFRM': 1, 'HAVE_WMEMCMP': 1, 'HAVE_WORKING_TZSET': 1, 'HAVE_WRITEV': 1, 'HAVE_ZLIB_COPY': 1, 'HAVE__GETPTY': 0, 'HOST_GNU_TYPE': 'x86_64-pc-linux-gnu', 'INCLDIRSTOMAKE': '/usr/include /usr/include /usr/include/python3.6m /usr/include/python3.6m', 'INCLUDEDIR': '/usr/include', 'INCLUDEPY': '/usr/include/python3.6m', 'INSTALL': '/usr/bin/install -c', 'INSTALL_DATA': '/usr/bin/install -c -m 644', 'INSTALL_PROGRAM': '/usr/bin/install -c', 'INSTALL_SCRIPT': '/usr/bin/install -c', 'INSTALL_SHARED': '/usr/bin/install -c -m 555', 'INSTSONAME': 'libpython3.6m.so.1.0', 'IO_H': 'Modules/_io/_iomodule.h', 'IO_OBJS': '\\', 'LDCXXSHARED': 'x86_64-linux-gnu-g++ -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions', 'LDFLAGS': '-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-link.specs -Wl,-z,relro', 'LDLAST': '', 'LDLIBRARY': 'libpython3.6m.so', 'LDLIBRARYDIR': '', 'LDSHARED': 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-link.specs -Wl,-z,relro', 'LDVERSION': '3.6m', 'LIBC': '', 'LIBDEST': '/usr/lib/python3.6', 'LIBDIR': '/usr/lib', 'LIBFFI_INCLUDEDIR': '', 'LIBM': '-lm', 'LIBOBJDIR': 'Python/', 'LIBOBJS': '', 'LIBPC': '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig', 'LIBPL': '/usr/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu', 'LIBRARY': 'libpython3.6m.a', 'LIBRARY_OBJS': '\\', 'LIBRARY_OBJS_OMIT_FROZEN': '\\', 'LIBS': '-lpthread -ldl  -lutil', 'LIBSUBDIRS': 'tkinter tkinter/test tkinter/test/test_tkinter \\', 'LINKCC': 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread', 'LINKFORSHARED': '-Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions', 'LIPO_32BIT_FLAGS': '', 'LLVM_PROF_ERR': 'no', 'LLVM_PROF_FILE': '', 'LLVM_PROF_MERGER': 'true', 'LN': 'ln', 'LOCALMODLIBS': '-lexpat                     -L/usr/lib -lz  -lexpat', 'LOG1P_DROPS_ZERO_SIGN': 0, 'MACHDEP': 'linux', 'MACHDEPPATH': ':', 'MACHDEP_OBJS': '', 'MACHDESTLIB': '/usr/lib/python3.6', 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET': '', 'MAINCC': 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread', 'MAJOR_IN_MKDEV': 0, 'MAJOR_IN_SYSMACROS': 0, 'MAKESETUP': '../Modules/makesetup', 'MANDIR': '/usr/share/man', 'MKDIR_P': '/bin/mkdir -p', 'MODLIBS': '-lexpat                     -L/usr/lib -lz  -lexpat', 'MODNAMES': '_thread array math _struct _random _elementtree _pickle _datetime _bisect _heapq unicodedata fcntl spwd grp select _socket _posixsubprocess _md5 _sha1 _sha256 _sha512 _sha3 _blake2 syslog binascii zlib pyexpat posix errno pwd _sre _codecs _weakref _functools _operator _collections itertools atexit _signal _stat time _locale _io zipimport faulthandler _tracemalloc _symtable xxsubtype', 'MODOBJS': 'Modules/_threadmodule.o  Modules/arraymodule.o  Modules/mathmodule.o Modules/_math.o  Modules/_struct.o  Modules/_randommodule.o  Modules/_elementtree.o  Modules/_pickle.o  Modules/_datetimemodule.o  Modules/_bisectmodule.o  Modules/_heapqmodule.o  Modules/unicodedata.o  Modules/fcntlmodule.o  Modules/spwdmodule.o  Modules/grpmodule.o  Modules/selectmodule.o  Modules/socketmodule.o  Modules/_posixsubprocess.o  Modules/md5module.o  Modules/sha1module.o  Modules/sha256module.o  Modules/sha512module.o  Modules/sha3module.o  Modules/blake2module.o Modules/blake2b_impl.o Modules/blake2s_impl.o  Modules/syslogmodule.o  Modules/binascii.o  Modules/zlibmodule.o  Modules/pyexpat.o  Modules/posixmodule.o  Modules/errnomodule.o  Modules/pwdmodule.o  Modules/_sre.o  Modules/_codecsmodule.o  Modules/_weakref.o  Modules/_functoolsmodule.o  Modules/_operator.o  Modules/_collectionsmodule.o  Modules/itertoolsmodule.o  Modules/atexitmodule.o  Modules/signalmodule.o  Modules/_stat.o  Modules/timemodule.o  Modules/_localemodule.o  Modules/_iomodule.o Modules/iobase.o Modules/fileio.o Modules/bytesio.o Modules/bufferedio.o Modules/textio.o Modules/stringio.o  Modules/zipimport.o  Modules/faulthandler.o  Modules/_tracemalloc.o Modules/hashtable.o  Modules/symtablemodule.o  Modules/xxsubtype.o', 'MODULE_OBJS': '\\', 'MULTIARCH': 'x86_64-linux-gnu', 'MULTIARCH_CPPFLAGS': '-DMULTIARCH=\\"x86_64-linux-gnu\\"', 'MVWDELCH_IS_EXPRESSION': 1, 'NO_AS_NEEDED': '-Wl,--no-as-needed', 'OBJECT_OBJS': '\\', 'OPT': '-DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes', 'OTHER_LIBTOOL_OPT': '', 'PACKAGE_BUGREPORT': 0, 'PACKAGE_NAME': 0, 'PACKAGE_STRING': 0, 'PACKAGE_TARNAME': 0, 'PACKAGE_URL': 0, 'PACKAGE_VERSION': 0, 'PARSER_HEADERS': '\\', 'PARSER_OBJS': '\\ Parser/myreadline.o Parser/parsetok.o Parser/tokenizer.o', 'PGEN': 'Parser/pgen', 'PGENOBJS': '\\ \\', 'PGOBJS': '\\', 'PGO_PROF_GEN_FLAG': '-fprofile-generate', 'PGO_PROF_USE_FLAG': '', 'PLATDIR': '', 'POBJS': '\\', 'POSIX_SEMAPHORES_NOT_ENABLED': 0, 'PROFILE_TASK': '-m test.regrtest --pgo', 'PTHREAD_SYSTEM_SCHED_SUPPORTED': 1, 'PURIFY': '', 'PY3LIBRARY': 'libpython3.so', 'PYLONG_BITS_IN_DIGIT': 0, 'PYTHON': 'python', 'PYTHONFRAMEWORK': '', 'PYTHONFRAMEWORKDIR': 'no-framework', 'PYTHONFRAMEWORKINSTALLDIR': '', 'PYTHONFRAMEWORKPREFIX': '', 'PYTHONPATH': ':', 'PYTHON_FOR_BUILD': './python -E', 'PYTHON_FOR_REGEN': 'python3.6', 'PYTHON_HEADERS': '\\', 'PYTHON_OBJS': '\\', 'PY_CFLAGS': '-Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.6-sXpGnM/python3.6-3.6.3=. -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-compile.specs -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security', 'PY_CFLAGS_NODIST': '-std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers', 'PY_CORE_CFLAGS': '-Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.6-sXpGnM/python3.6-3.6.3=. -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-compile.specs -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -IObjects -IInclude -IPython -I. -I../Include -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPy_BUILD_CORE', 'PY_CPPFLAGS': '-IObjects -IInclude -IPython -I. -I../Include -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2', 'PY_FORMAT_SIZE_T': '"z"', 'PY_LDFLAGS': '-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-link.specs -Wl,-z,relro', 'Py_DEBUG': 0, 'Py_ENABLE_SHARED': 1, 'Py_HASH_ALGORITHM': 0, 'QUICKTESTOPTS': '-x test_subprocess test_io test_lib2to3 \\', 'RANLIB': 'x86_64-linux-gnu-ranlib', 'READELF': 'readelf', 'RESSRCDIR': 'Mac/Resources/framework', 'RETSIGTYPE': 'void', 'RUNSHARED': 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/build/python3.6-sXpGnM/python3.6-3.6.3/build-shared', 'SCRIPTDIR': '/usr/lib', 'SETPGRP_HAVE_ARG': 0, 'SGI_ABI': '', 'SHELL': '/bin/sh', 'SHLIBS': '-lpthread -ldl  -lutil', 'SHLIB_SUFFIX': '.so', 'SIGNED_RIGHT_SHIFT_ZERO_FILLS': 0, 'SITEPATH': '', 'SIZEOF_DOUBLE': 8, 'SIZEOF_FLOAT': 4, 'SIZEOF_FPOS_T': 16, 'SIZEOF_INT': 4, 'SIZEOF_LONG': 8, 'SIZEOF_LONG_DOUBLE': 16, 'SIZEOF_LONG_LONG': 8, 'SIZEOF_OFF_T': 8, 'SIZEOF_PID_T': 4, 'SIZEOF_PTHREAD_T': 8, 'SIZEOF_SHORT': 2, 'SIZEOF_SIZE_T': 8, 'SIZEOF_TIME_T': 8, 'SIZEOF_UINTPTR_T': 8, 'SIZEOF_VOID_P': 8, 'SIZEOF_WCHAR_T': 4, 'SIZEOF__BOOL': 1, 'SOABI': 'cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu', 'SRCDIRS': 'Parser Grammar Objects Python Modules Mac Programs', 'SRC_GDB_HOOKS': '../Tools/gdb/libpython.py', 'STDC_HEADERS': 1, 'STRICT_SYSV_CURSES': "/* Don't use ncurses extensions */", 'STRIPFLAG': '-s', 'SUBDIRS': '', 'SUBDIRSTOO': 'Include Lib Misc', 'SYSLIBS': '-lm', 'SYS_SELECT_WITH_SYS_TIME': 1, 'TANH_PRESERVES_ZERO_SIGN': 1, 'TCLTK_INCLUDES': '', 'TCLTK_LIBS': '', 'TESTOPTS': '', 'TESTPATH': '', 'TESTPYTHON': 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/build/python3.6-sXpGnM/python3.6-3.6.3/build-shared ./python', 'TESTPYTHONOPTS': '', 'TESTRUNNER': 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/build/python3.6-sXpGnM/python3.6-3.6.3/build-shared ./python ../Tools/scripts/run_tests.py', 'TESTTIMEOUT': 1200, 'THREADOBJ': 'Python/thread.o', 'TIMEMODULE_LIB': 0, 'TIME_WITH_SYS_TIME': 1, 'TM_IN_SYS_TIME': 0, 'UNICODE_DEPS': '\\', 'UNIVERSALSDK': '', 'USE_COMPUTED_GOTOS': 1, 'USE_INLINE': 1, 'VERSION': '3.6', 'VPATH': '..', 'WANT_SIGFPE_HANDLER': 0, 'WINDOW_HAS_FLAGS': 1, 'WITH_DOC_STRINGS': 1, 'WITH_DTRACE': 0, 'WITH_DYLD': 0, 'WITH_LIBINTL': 0, 'WITH_NEXT_FRAMEWORK': 0, 'WITH_PYMALLOC': 1, 'WITH_THREAD': 1, 'WITH_VALGRIND': 0, 'X87_DOUBLE_ROUNDING': 0, 'XMLLIBSUBDIRS': 'xml xml/dom xml/etree xml/parsers xml/sax', 'abs_builddir': '/build/python3.6-sXpGnM/python3.6-3.6.3/build-shared', 'abs_srcdir': '/build/python3.6-sXpGnM/python3.6-3.6.3/build-shared/..', 'datarootdir': '/usr/share', 'srcdir': '/usr/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu', 'SO': '.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so', 'userbase': '/home/kruqer/.local', 'multiarchsubdir': '/x86_64-linux-gnu'}
```

Python

```
2.7.14
```

Python3

```
3.6.3
```

pip:

```
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

pip3:

```
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)
```

pip list:

```
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
asn1crypto (0.22.0)
attrs (17.2.0)
beautifulsoup4 (4.6.0)
certifi (2017.11.5)
chardet (3.0.4)
click (6.7)
colorama (0.3.7)
constantly (15.1.0)
cryptography (1.9)
Cython (0.27.3)
docutils (0.14)
enum34 (1.1.6)
html5lib (0.999999999)
idna (2.5)
incremental (16.10.1)
ipaddress (1.0.17)
keyring (10.4.0)
keyrings.alt (2.2)
Kivy (1.10.0)
lxml (4.0.0)
mercurial (4.3.1)
numpy (1.12.1)
olefile (0.44)
PAM (0.4.2)
Parsley (1.2)
Pillow (4.1.1)
pip (9.0.1)
psutil (5.0.1)
pyasn1 (0.1.9)
pyasn1-modules (0.0.7)
pycrypto (2.6.1)
Pygments (2.2.0)
pygobject (3.24.1)
pyliblzma (0.5.3)
pyOpenSSL (16.2.0)
pyserial (3.4)
pyxdg (0.25)
requests (2.18.4)
roman (2.0.0)
scour (0.32)
SecretStorage (2.3.1)
service-identity (16.0.0)
setuptools (36.2.7)
six (1.10.0)
torbrowser-launcher (0.2.7)
Twisted (16.6.0)
txsocksx (0.0.0)
urllib3 (1.22)
webencodings (0.5)
wheel (0.29.0)
zope.interface (4.3.2)
```

$PATH:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Comment: This is usually a problem when you install a package with a Python installation that was compiled with the [`fpectl`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fpectl.html) module (`--with-fpectl` compilation flag), and then switch to a Python installation that was compiled without this flag. I suppose in your case it would suffice to reinstall `kivy`.

Comment: I reinstalled kivy many times, using apt, using pip for python2.7, using pip3, and the problem persists. I am a beginner, and I do not understand very well what you told me about my installation of python. So how can I use a "good" python, can you suggest me some commands to reinstall cleanly a good version of python? Thanks.

Comment: Please run `$ python -c "import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_config_vars())"` and update the answer with the output; maybe this will shed some light on the problem...

Comment: Ok, so at least your `python2` does not have `fpectl`, now run the same sommand with `python3`. While we're at it, please also run `python -V`, `python3 -V`, `pip -V`, `pip3 -V`, `pip list`, `pip3 list` and `echo $PATH`.

Comment: I edited the post to add some informations. Will I success to solve my problem by installing kivy in a OS in a VM ? If yes, which OS ?

Answer (score 1):

I've just figured it out. I solve it out by uninstalling the cython module and then reinstalling a different version of it. As the official documentation says, there is not any kind of guarantee if the newer versions work fine while compilation. So, first uninstall cython:

```
pip uninstall cython
```

Install the version 0.23:

```
pip install cython==0.23
```

And then again install Kivy, and make sure there's no error while compilation:

```
pip install kivy
```

Hope, this will work fine.